# "Unknown" PHP error - what is that supposed to mean?

Tags: php, header, buffer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “Headers already sent” error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

> [Mon Jan 10 21:01:26 2011] [error] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx] PHP Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in Unknown on line 0, referer: www.example.com/some.php

Why PHP is not able to locate where the headers were sent from?

Comment: Are you echoingsomething above header? Remove the whole blankspave on the top of the page ans put <?php  tag on the topmost and leftmost :)

Comment: Try googling it.  There's tons of information out there on this.

Comment: Everyone tries to help ts with "headers already sent" problem, but he only needs to know what does "Unknown" stands for...

Comment: @ircmaxell but I don't see anything usable. Note the `Unknown on line 0`

Comment: @Pekka: The other discussion linked above seems to identify the cause of the problem. http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=9031

Comment: @nico: from the PHP bugs page: "[2001-06-14 12:49 UTC] Problem has already been solved in php 4.0.5.", however I'm using the latest version. Notice, that it appeared somewhere in 2001, 9 years ago. There must be other reason.

Comment: @Sarah: are you using `ob_start("ob_gzhandler");`? Anyway, the problem seemed to be due to a memory leak, so I would try to find the culprit and file a bug report.

Comment: @Sarah - how are they not the same? Same error message, with the same "I have no clue what this means" question text. See also: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/

Comment: @ken Dont you find it strange, that php does not know where the headers are modified? Edited: ok, as I understood, it's because of ob_start() function..

Answer (score -1):

See if you have a space after `<?`. The header function is quite sensitive and doesnt work if anything is outputted before hand.

Comment: You must mean `before <?` or possibly `after ?>`

Comment: if the files are unicode there might be an invisible BOM before the '<?' causing output before php even starts. Refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark